# Incorrect headrule size in landscape page

Tags: landscape, typearea, headline, leaders

The following codes creat a three-page document with `wavedot` headrule, and the middle page is landscape made by `typearea`.

The problem is: the headrule in the landscape page does not fill up the textwidth, wheares it works fine in portrait pages.

What's the reason and how to make headrule in each page draw with correct size?

**Codes:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr,xcolor}
\usepackage[usegeometry]{typearea}
\geometry{showframe}
\pagestyle{fancy}\fancyhf{}

\newcommand\landscapepageon[1][]
{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \savegeometry{prelandscape}
  \KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,DIV=current,#1}
  \recalctypearea
  \bgroup
}
\newcommand\landscapepageoff{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \egroup
  \KOMAoptions{paper=portrait}
  \recalctypearea
  \loadgeometry{prelandscape}
}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{%
  \bfseries\color{red}\leavevmode\cleaders\hbox{${\sim}{\cdot}$}\hfill\null%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
\begin{document}
portait page
\landscapepageon
landscape page
\landscapepageoff
portrait page again
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the width of head of the mid page is same as the first page.

I am not sure but the following is OK for these three pages.

```
\renewcommand{\headrule}{%
  \makebox[\textwidth][s]{\bfseries\color{red}\leavevmode\cleaders\hbox{${\sim}{\cdot}$}\hfill\null}%
}
```

Just add a box with `\textwidth` to your `\headrule`.

Comment: Simple but elegant solution! Many thanks! From the manuel of `fancyhdr`, `The width of headers and footers is \headwidth, which by default equals the width of the text: \textwidth`. I try with `\makebox[\headwidth]...`, but the headrule in landscape page does not fill up the header space either.  Why?

Comment: And `typearea` does not recalculate `\headwidth`?